# What's the efficient way to count duplicates of each pair of a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, duplicates, std-pair

Is there any efficient way to count duplicates of each pair in a vector?
For example, if I have a vector like this:

```
 vector<pair<int, int> > duplicates={{1,2},{3,2},{2,1},{5,6},{5,6},{1,2},{2,1},{5,6}};
```

The output should be:

```
 {1,2}:2
 {3,2}:1
 {2,1}:2
 {5,6}:3
```

And TO be CLEAR, I am just curious about how to solve this problem more efficiently. I have tried to compare each pair of this vector and it seems not a smart way.

Comment: Hint: use an associative container which detects duplicates.

Comment: SO is here to help you do things, not to do them for you. You should show what you have tried already.

Comment: @PaulRooney I think, there is no problem for this question. Lixum only ask for technics or logics, not for coded solution.

Comment: @ShohanAhmedSijan  The OP should clarify what they are looking for, which is why this question is being downvoted.

Comment: @ShohanAhmedSijan yeah, you are right. I am curious about how to solve this problem more efficiently. I have tried to compare each pair of this vector and it seems not a smart way.

Comment: @LixunBai if what you are after is more efficient version then why not post your less efficient version?

Comment: *I am just curious about how to solve this problem more efficiently.* -- Hash table and a counter -- but that is what `std::unordered_map` is all about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way is to use a map or unordered map to count them:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
int main( int argn, char **argc)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > duplicates={{1,2},{3,2},{2,1},{5,6},{5,6},{1,2},{2,1},{5,6}};
    std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int> checker;
    for (const auto &elem: duplicates)
    {
        ++checker[elem];
    }

    for (const auto &elem: checker) std::cout << "{" << elem.first.first <<
                                                 "," << elem.first.second <<
                                                 "}: " << elem.second << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

> Note that map insertion/recovery is O(log(n)), and the loop around make it aprox. O(n*log(n))

EDIT:

Following the additional note of the OP, here is a better (faster) implementation using unordered_map:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace std
{
template <>
struct hash<std::pair<int,int>>
{
    size_t operator()(pair<int, int> const &p) const
    {
        // Fine for 64bit size_t and 32bit int. Otherwise, some collision may happens.
        size_t result = (static_cast<size_t>(p.first) <<(sizeof(std::size_t)<<2))
                        + static_cast<size_t>(p.second);
        return result;
    }
};
}

int main( int argn, char **argc)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > duplicates={{1,2},{3,2},{2,1},{5,6},{5,6},{1,2},{2,1},{5,6}};
    std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, int> checker;
    for (const auto &elem: duplicates)
    {
        ++checker[elem]; // value initialized with 0
    }

    for (const auto &elem: checker) std::cout << "{" << elem.first.first <<
                                                 "," << elem.first.second <<
                                                 "}: " << elem.second << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

> Insertion in unordered_map, using a hash make it usually constant (worse case when there are collision is linear). Final complexity in average is O(N)

Comment: There is no need for the `if` statement.

Comment: The `if (checker.find(elem)==checker.end()) checker[elem] = 1; else` part is redundant.

Comment: Your latest edit still has the `if` statement -- get rid of it.

Comment: @AdrianMaire The counter is automatically started at 0.  That is the default initial value for `int`.

Comment: @AdrianMaire [Read the `std::map` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)

Comment: Check the behavior of `std::map::operator[]` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at), especially the part of "when key does not exist..."

Comment: @AdrianMaire -- What is `it`?  You're making this much harder [than it should be, as this example shows](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/483cfe1ee4cf52e0)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: sorry, but your example is exactly the same.

Comment: @AdrianMaire -- So through all of that, you've finally made the change that was suggested in the first two comments.  See how simple that was?

Comment: To be honest, I did not know about initialization of basic type in maps. The number of your comments just overwhelmed me a bit.

Comment: @AdrianMaire That is a good thing, if we can learn something new everyday on SO. :)

Comment: @AdrianMaire Brilliant! Elegant code with high performance. I learn a lot from the code and your comments. I just start my C++ journey and I hope someday I can code like this! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple solution:

1. Sort vector of pairs
2. Then just a loop if match consecutive pairs then increase counter

General search Complexity: n*n
This search Complexity: nlog(n)